# Язык СИ, ввод и команда в консоли

Tags: c

помогите пожалуйста, не знаю как написать функцию. 
У меня есть программа, база данных, рабочая. Надо написать функцию, которая будет называться where , фильтр так сказать. Эта функция будет показывать на экран только те значения, которые мне надо. Эта функция будет похожа на функцию show в main.

После запуска программы в консоль напишите `show all` или `show 3` например, а после этого надо  написать `where plat < 2000` или `where meno > g`, 
`where datum = 15 6 1988`. 
Вот так правильно написать `show all where plat < 2000` или 
`show 3 where datum > 1 1 2000`.

Помогите пожалуйста написать такую функцию, может мыслями или напишите пожалуйста, срочно надо, а понятия не имею, мыслей 0 об этом. 
Фотографию пример можете посмотреть внизу как и код. [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>

    #define MAX_LEN 10
    #define MAX_ZAM 10 // kol zam

    char* pozicie[3] = {"dizaner", "developer", "tester"};
        // struct
    typedef struct {
        int den, mesiac, rok;
    }Datum;

    typedef struct {
        char meno[MAX_LEN];
        Datum d_narodeniea;
    }Osobneudaje;

    typedef struct {
        int id;
        char pozicia[MAX_LEN];
        double plat;
        Osobneudaje udaje;
    }Zamestnanec;


    int medzeryNAvypis();
    Zamestnanec genZamestnanec();
    void genZamenestnacov(Zamestnanec db[], int n);
    void printALL(Zamestnanec db[], int n);





    int main() {
        srand((unsigned int) time(0));
        Zamestnanec db[MAX_ZAM];
        printf("\n");
        printf("%3.s ID | Plat |");
        printf("\n....................................................\n");

        genZamestnanec();//gen zamestnanec
        genZamenestnacov(db, MAX_ZAM); // vygener zamestnancov
        printALL(db, MAX_ZAM); //print zamest
        //max dlzka
        char prikaz[MAX_LEN];
        char slovo[MAX_LEN];

// show funk
        int off = 0;
        while(fgets(prikaz, MAX_LEN, stdin)){//!=NULL
        off = 0;
        printf("%s", prikaz);

        sscanf(prikaz, "%s", slovo); //sscanf(prikaz+off, "%s", slovo);
    if(strcmp(slovo, "show")){ //if(!strcmp(slovo, "show")){
        //printf("to je slovo show\n");
        //printALL(db, MAX_ZAM);
        continue;
    }

        off += strlen(slovo);
    if(sscanf(prikaz+off, "%s", slovo)==1){
    if(!strcmp(slovo, "all")){
        printALL(db, MAX_ZAM);
    }else{
        int c = atoi(slovo);
    if(c > MAX_ZAM){
        printf("Data-baza ma %d zamestnancv\n", MAX_ZAM);
        continue;
    }
        printALL(db, c);
    }
    }
        off += strlen(slovo);
    if(sscanf(prikaz+off, "%s", slovo)==1){
    if(!strcmp(slovo, "where")){
        printALL(db, MAX_ZAM);
    }
    }
    }
     }

    //generacia
    Zamestnanec genZamestnanec(){
        Zamestnanec z;
        z.id = rand()%1000;
        z.plat = rand()%2000 + 2000;
        strcpy(z.pozicia, pozicie[rand()%3]);
        int rand_len = rand()%MAX_LEN;
    for (int i = 0; i < rand_len; ++i) {
        z.udaje.meno[i] = rand()%('z'-'a') + 'a';
    }
        z.udaje.meno[rand_len] = '\0';
        z.udaje.d_narodeniea.den = rand()%31+1;
        z.udaje.d_narodeniea.mesiac = rand()%1+12;
        z.udaje.d_narodeniea.rok = rand()% (2019-1980) + 1980;

    return z;
    }


    void genZamenestnacov(Zamestnanec db[], int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        db[i] = genZamestnanec();
    }
    }

    //vyvod print
    void printZamestnanec(const Zamestnanec* z){

        printf(" %5.d | %8.2lf | %6s | %2s | %d/%d/%d\n",
        z->id,
        z->plat,
        z->pozicia,
        z->udaje.meno,
        z->udaje.d_narodeniea.den,
        z->udaje.d_narodeniea.mesiac,
        z->udaje.d_narodeniea.rok);

    }

    void printALL(Zamestnanec db[], int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printZamestnanec(&db[i]);
    }
        printf("\n Prikaz: ");
    }
```

Comment: Уточните условие задачи. Если допускаются сложные (составные) условия вида *ID != 15 AND datum > 1 1 2000*, тогда дело плохо - надо писать полноценный синтаксический анализатор.  Если же после слова *where*  допускается использовать только одно условие строго фиксированного вида: *<колонка БД> <Знак операции отношения>  <Константа>*, тогда ситуация значительно проще.

Comment: да, только одно условие

Comment: show all where plat < 2000

Comment: или же 
show 3 where datum > 1 1 2000
это день, месяц, год

Comment: нет. так. 
сначала будет команда   show  , а потом уже команда  where

Comment: @Sergey , то есть show [ число | all ]  where [ plat | pozicia | meno | datum ] [ < | = | > ] значение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
show [ число | all ] where [ plat | pozicia | meno | datum ] [ < | = | > ] значение
```

Ну до where вы уже разбор командной строки организовали - повторять не буду.

Далее:

1. Берёте остаток строки и проверяете - есть ли там фраза where в начале строки.
2. Если такая фраза есть, то в цикле, перед печатью очередной записи, вызываете некую логическую функцию вроде *int check_record(char *tail, const Zamestnanec* z)* и проверяете её код возрата. Если 0 - то печатать не нужно, если не 0 - вызываете свою функцию *printZamestnanec*
3. Внутри себя эта функция проверяет первое слово и если оно *plat*, то:
4. Выделяете остаток командной строки после имени переменной
5. Вызываете некую функцию *compare_plat(char *new_tail, const Zamestnanec* z)* которая и выполняет сравнение.

Естественно, что Вы должны проверить ещё три условия (pozicia | meno | datum) и, при совпадении, вызывать соответствующую ф-цию сравнения.

Функция *check_record* в итоге возвращает результат сравнения, который ей передадут функции сравнения конкретных переменных.

Ну а по результату сравнения будете решать - печатать, или - нет.